# Need help on where i should call a virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, virtual-functions

Sorry for the long ass code, let me explain briefly. I made a main class - Worker and two derived classes - hourlyworker, salaried worker. I made a virtual function that calculates a salary, no need to explain it, that's not my question.

### I read an input, here's an example:

3 //first digit i read determines how many workers i'm going to have

dave sal

steve hou

chris sal //those 3 lines show names of workers and if they are paid with salary or hourly

10 20 10 //the working hours of those 3 workers, in that order.

---

Here's what i want to do: Depending on the type of payment each worker gets (hou or sal) i calculate his salary, calling the virtual function compute_pay. 
Example output:

dave 400

steve 200

chris 400.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Worker {
public:
    void print();
protected:
    string name;
    string type;
};

class HourlyWorker : public  Worker {
public:
    HourlyWorker(string n) {
        name = n;
    }
    virtual double compute_pay(int hours) {
        double payment = 10;
        if (hours <= 40) {
            return hours * payment;
        }
        else {
            return (40 * payment) + ((hours - 40) * payment * 1.5);
        }
    }
    void print(int a) {
        cout << name << "  " << a << "\n";
    }
private:
    string name;
    string type;
}

class SalariedWorker : public Worker{
public:
    SalariedWorker(string n) {
        name = n;
    }
    virtual double compute_pay(int hours) {
        hours = 40;
        int payment = 10;
        return payment * hours;
    }
    void print(int a) {
        cout << name << "  " << a << "\n";
    }
private:
    string name;
    string type;
};

void print(vector<SalariedWorker*> sal, int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sal.size(); i++)
        sal[i]->print(a);
}
void print(vector<HourlyWorker*> sal, int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sal.size(); i++)
        sal[i]->print(a);
}

int main()
{
    vector<SalariedWorker*> sal;
    vector<HourlyWorker*> hour;
    int first; //first digit
    int hours; //hours of each worker
    string name; //name or worker
    string type; //sal or hou
    cout << "go" << "\n";
    cin >> first;
    for (int i = 0; i < first+1; i++) {
        if (i < first) {
            cin >> name >> type;
            if (type == "sal") {
                SalariedWorker* sall = new SalariedWorker(name);
                sal.push_back(sall); //If a worker is "sal" i write into the HourlyWorker vector
            }
            else if (type == "hou") {
                HourlyWorker* hourr = new HourlyWorker(name);
                hour.push_back(hourr);
            } //If a worker is "hou" i write into the HourlyWorker vector
            else {
                cout << "Wrong input" << "\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else { //This triggers when we reach the last line. It triggers only once
            for (int z = 0; z < first; z++) {
                cin >> hours; //reading the last line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, sorry for the long code, you don't have to go trough all of it, just the main class, and more importantly - the loop.
Here's my question: where exactly should i call my compute_pay function so that it goes thorugh all the lines, assuming the int variable it requiers is the int hours variable i read at the last line?
Also, where should i call my print function afterwards so i can see my output?
I know it's a stupid or complicated question, but i honestly tried my best and I cannot figure it out :/.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's very hard to understand. "Where exactly should I call my `compute_pay` function so that it goes through all the lines" - what lines? What does it mean for `compute_pay` to "go through" a line? As written, `compute_pay` doesn't "go through" anything.

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. By lines i meant input lines. Here's an example of how it should work: 1 - It reads a name of a person. 2 - It reads sal/hou (payment method) and depending on that it puts the person in one of the two vectors - sal, hour. 3 - After it reads all the names it reads one more line - the work hours for every worker. First digit is for first worker, second for second, etc. After doing so, depending on the type of payment - sal/hou it calls the function compute_pay and that way it calculates the payment. Should i call it the while reading the last line or afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you  have different derivations of `Worker` with their own implementation of `compute_pay`. What having a virtual `compute_pay` does, is let you use the base class generically, without needing to have separate lists of each type.

To generically use virtual methods, you need an abstract base class. This means that the base class needs a virtual method declaration (as well as a virtual destructor):

```cpp
class Worker {
public:
    virtual double compute_pay(int hours) = 0;
    virtual ~Worker() = default;
    /* all the other members go here */
};
```

The virtual destructor is an important part of this - it means that the correct destructor will be called no matter what type of pointer you're using. The `= 0` means it's a *pure virtual* method, which is not implemented and will break if you try and declare a base `Worker` instead of a derived one.

Derived classes must *override* that base virtual method with the logic unique to that class:

```cpp
class WorkerA {
public:
    double compute_pay(int hours) override { /* whatever */ return 42.0; }
};
class WorkerB {
public:
    double compute_pay(int hours) override { /* whatever */ return 25.0; }
};
```

Note that the derived classes don't use `virtual`, but instead add `override` to communicate that they're supposed to override a virtual base method.

Then, you can have *one* vector of workers:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> workers;

if (use_worker_a) {
    workers.emplace_back(new WorkerA());
} else {
    workers.emplace_back(new WorkerB());
}
```

Note: use a smart pointer such as `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers whenever you can so you don't have to worry about explicitly deleting them.

The base virtual methods can then be used from that vector, without caring which pointer is which derived type:

```cpp
double sum = 0;
for (auto& worker : workers) {
    sum += worker->compute_pay(40);
}
```

All the stuff about computing the number of hours, reading from a file, etc, I'll leave that to you. But that's how you use virtual methods for dynamic dispatch  effectively.